# Access symfony form widget value by id using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, twig

I am using symfony 3 generated forms. In order to validate the form I want to access the form widget value (text inputs in html) using javascript.

The problem is this: I cannot access the text input(widget) of a symfony generated form by id or name in javascript, I have already added id and name attribute to the widget but still cannot access it in javascript.

This is the formType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder ->add('titre', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class'                       => 'form-control',
                'type'=>"text",
                'name'=>"titre" ,
                'id'=>"titre",
                'placeholder'=>"*TITRE"
            ]
        ])
         ->add('Ajouter' ,SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => [
                 'class'=>"btn",
                        'id'=>"btn_submit",
        'onClick'=>"checkifValid();"]]
                );
    }
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById("titre").value = "test";
alert( document.getElementById("titre").value);
//iam just testing if i am accessing to it's value or not
})
</script>
```

Comment: It is likely that the full id of the form field is not simply `titre`. For example, if your form class is `Foo` the id might be `foo_titre`. Your browser may have tools to allow inspecting the html source to confirm the full name.

Comment: @geoB what's the relation between the css class and the input id ?

Comment: If your question is about my comment on form class, that class is the one in which your `public function buildForm(...)` appears, not a css class. For example, I have a form class `MemberType` that includes a text field `fname`. When the form is rendered the html source includes `<input id="member_fname"...>`

Comment: @geoB you are right , thank you for your answer it's resolved

Comment: yes i will @geoB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the id of the field as rendered in the html source will include the name of the form type in which your field is defined. For example, for the form type `MemberType` containing a text field `fname`, the html source will include `<input id="member_fname"...>`. A jquery reference to that field would then be `$("#member_fname")`. The best way to confirm all this is to use your browser's source code display to check the id of the rendered form field.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you add attr values in your twig template (also to your forms) and not in the form builder... If you do this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, { 'id': 'foo' }) }}
```

... **your form** widget's **id sure will be foo (and dont bar_foo where bar originated from the typeclass name**), furthermore, you keep more the MVC (or this MVC like symfony) pattern.

[symfony/doc/3.4/#more-about-form-variables](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#more-about-form-variables)

Directly about [symfony.com/doc/3.4/#form-variables-reference](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference), but the point:

form: The current FormView instance.

name: The name of the field (e.g. title) - but not the name HTML attribute, which is full_name.

So in your case:

```
{{ form_start(your_form, {'attr': {'id': 'your_form_id'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(your_form.titre, {'id': 'titre', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
{{ form_end(your_form) }}
```

*So really, thinking about, when you add class names and ids to your form inside the php formBuilder (so in the backend), between the frontend guy working on the html/twig, css and the js parts of the app... I dont think so, this is a good idea.*

Comment: sorry but your answer didn't help

Comment: I update my answer with symfony 3 documents, but this should work... What is the problem or error message about twig form variables? Anyway, when I wrote: `your form ... id sure will be foo (and dont bar_foo where bar originated from the typeclass name` <--- This absolutely the same, what geoB suggest to you.